# MySQL stopped with a "Fatal Error" and requires restarting

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am hosting a WordPress site on a Digital Ocean instance that is an unmanaged cloud instance. I previously sometime had a problem that when I went to my site, it said "Database Connection not established". So then to make it work, I needed to restart MySQL service.

Now I am again getting same error and this time frequency is also high. So I went to error log and I think this part, I am pasting here point towards the problem:

```
    141123  3:15:39 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
141123  3:15:39 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
141123  3:15:39 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
141123  3:15:39 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(135987200 bytes) failed; errno 12
141123  3:15:39 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
141123  3:15:39 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
141123  3:15:39 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
141123  3:15:39 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
141123  3:15:39 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
141123  3:15:39 [ERROR] Aborting
```

So I think problem is because it can't allocate memory for buffer pool and as this is Fatal Error then this is probably what stops MySQL. But I don't know how to fix it and is this the actual thing that is causing the problem? So is it something related to Server configuration or there can be some wild query in my code?

### Update

After trying fix of @Sajidkhan (one of answers below). Sill mysql is shutting down after some time, however log is bit different this time. Below is what I can see now.

```
141206 14:38:59 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
141206 14:38:59 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
141206 14:38:59 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
141206 14:38:59 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
141206 14:38:59 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
141206 14:38:59 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
141206 14:38:59 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
141206 14:38:59  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
141206 14:38:59  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
141206 14:39:00 InnoDB: 5.5.31 started; log sequence number 512843890
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is this line:

```
141123  3:15:39 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
```

You should try creating a [swap file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04) or upgrading to the next plan on Digital Ocean.

Comment: Yes swap option is good one but does it mean that there is some of my plugin which is doing some heavy queries as there isn't much traffic or not lot of such content that should cause this problem. So do you think that other than creating swap file, it will helpful if I look into plugins queries e.t.c. too. ?

Comment: @Hafiz it wouldn't hurt to find out where your memory leak is just for good practice. You can try disabling all of your plugins and bringing them back online one by one and monitoring your usage. Sounds like you've got something bottle necking. I wouldn't consider this as an alternative to a swap file, I'd create one anyways.

Comment: I used the example told and came to know that I already have swap file and only currently using  `77/1023` MB while memory usage is `486/495` MB.  So what do you think, why swap file is being used so less while memory is almost being consumed so much ?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need skip-innodb (use case: low memory footprint), then of course you don't have to comment it out. However, if InnoDB is the default storage engine, the server will fail to start until you tell it which storage engine to use instead, e.g. default-storage-engine=myisam for MyISAM.

Try this:

```
sudo -u mysql mysqld --skip-innodb --default-storage-engine=myisam
```

Comment: but what if my Databases are using innodb as storage engine, so will that be affected by changing default storage engine? I mean we will be only changing default storage engine by above command so when it will need to use innodb then wouldn't same error occur again?

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work still db problem persist and MySQL is stopped